# How does alpha-beta pruning reduce run-time complexity?

Tags: minimax

I'm a bit confused about how alpha-beta pruning helps with run-time reduction for the minimax algorithm. Maybe my understanding of the minimax algorithm is wrong but I know that the naive version runs in O(b^d) where b is the branching factor and d is the search depth. Now with alpha-beta pruning we would reduce it to O(b^(3/4)d) on average. But doesn't the time taken to generate the game states still take O(b^d) time? Is the generation of all states not factored into the run-time of minimax, or is my understanding of the minimax algorithm wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Alpha-Beta does not reduce the speed at which the moves are being generated.

What does do however is reducing the amount of game branches to be searched through Alpha-Beta-Cutoffs. Since moves should be generated only after a branch is sure to be searched, the moves for the alpha-beta subbranches will not have to be calculated, thus reducing the time complexity.

[image: AB-Tree source:google]

In the above picture I marked the moves that do not have to be generated. As you can see, although the rightmost branch is cut off at layer 2, the moves *leading* to layer too are still generated. But the moves following *after* the cutoff are saved. This is where the complexity is reduced.

Comment: So what you're saying is it doesn't change the big O value of the algorithm but it will reduce the physical size of N?

Comment: No. It does indeed change the big O value. See answer, added picture.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :D Not my question but interesting anyway :D

Comment: Really interesting topic, I must admit. Thats why I wrote a chess engine as my high school grad work ;)

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out today and I was about to write an answer up